# Insufficient validation for 'name' using / +\w/. Use \A and \z as anchors

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I used brakeman for generating scanning reports in my application. It generated a Format Validation security warning with High Confidence in my model page:

> Insufficient validation for 'name' using / +\w/. Use \A and \z as
>   anchors near line 54

This is the line in my model where I am facing error:

```
validates_format_of :name, :with => / +\w/, :message => "must be your first and last name."
```

If there is no space in the name field, I am showing above validation. How can show it \A and\z format?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Brakeman is recommending the use of `\A` and `\z`-anchors in your validation regex. They define where the match has to start at (`\A`) and end at (`\z`). Without them, the regex can simply match to any part of the name. Let's transform your regex to encompass the whole string:

```
/\A\w+ +\w+\z/
```

You can remove the `+` after the space if you only want to accept one space.

Using the normal regex line begin (`^`) and end (`$`) anchors is also not recommended, because it would be enough to have one line which matches, and all other lines could be invalid.